# Why I always get the object with default parameters?

Tags: c++, constants

I have a problem with 2 member functions from which one is const returning a const:

```
const BoardNode & Board::getBoardNode(unsigned int rowIdx, unsigned int colIdx) const
{
    return _mData[rowIdx*_mNumColumns + colIdx];
}

BoardNode & Board::getBoardNode(unsigned int rowIdx, unsigned int colIdx)
{
    return _mData[rowIdx*_mNumColumns + colIdx];
}
```

After a while I use the code :

```
// where this is a Board holding Nodes in std::vector
BoardNode nodeToAddAsNeighbor   = this->getBoardNode(x1+ x, y1+ y);
```

Whatever the values of `y1`, `y`, `x`, `x1` are, I always return the node with coords `(0,0)`.

Nevertheless other parameters of the node are different only the coords are as mentioned above.

Any idea why ?

**EDIT**
My copy contructor :

```
BoardNode::BoardNode(const BoardNode & other) :
    _mNodeType(other._mNodeType),
    _coordinates( other._coordinates ),
    _neighboursVector( other._neighboursVector) {}
```

Comment: Try narrowing the problem down.

Comment: Of your copy constructor just does what the compiler-provided one would have done, don't explicitly define it.

Comment: Are you sure that the elements in `_mData` are set up properly? How are you constructing them?

Comment: The problem was my `_mData` - it wasn't constructed properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BoardNode nodeToAddAsNeighbor = ....;
```

invokes the copy constructor. Is it defined? How is it defined? Perhaps it doesn't work as advertised. E.g.

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    A(int i)    : i(i)  {}
    A(A const&) : i(42) {}
};
```

Obviously with

```
A a(7);
A b = a;
```

You can not expect b.i to contain 7, but rather it will contain 42

Comment: I added my copy contructor to the question

Answer (score 0):

Seems a problem with the copy constructor... Seems that copy constructor doesn't work well. Or maybe you don't fill data correctly. Try to understand what happen during copy constructor, and during insertion. 
In Debug mode try to see what it's inside _mData.

Ah it's not a good idea to start data member with an underscore it's better mData or m_data (it's faster to write too),

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to start members with underscores? Typing speed is subjective. I think the actual rules are a bit more nuanced